# Accessing global field values in site loop

Tags: multi-site, globals

I have a drop down select that I am populating with sites.
I've added a lightswitch field (handle 'showInDropDown') to the global set 'siteInfo' with the hope of getting the lightswitch value per site in the loop below.

```
{% for siteId in currentSite.group.sites %}
    {% set setForSiteId = craft.app.getGlobals().getSetByHandle('siteInfo', SiteId =5) %}
    {{ setForSiteId.showInDropdown }}
{% endfor %}
```

The lightswitch field is set to translate per site.
setForSiteId is always coming back null:

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("showInDropdown") on a null variable.
```

I am not sure if I am missing something. Is there another way to access global variables/values per site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved with the following code:

```
    <select  class="form-control " name="sites" id="company-select">
    <option value="" class="small text-muted">Please select your company</option>
    {% for site in allSites %}
        {% set siteId = site.id %}
        {% set groupId = site.getGroup().id %}
        {% if groupId == '5' %}
            {% set setForSiteId = craft.app.getGlobals().getSetByHandle('siteInfo', siteId) %}
            {% if setForSiteId.showInDropdown == '1' %}
            <option value="{{baseUrl ~ '/' ~ site.handle }}">{{site.name}}</option>
                {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
```